# Using Binary Search on Variant Array Created From an ADO Recordset

Tags: arrays, vb6, ado, binary-search

I'm using VB6 (yeah I know) to pull get an ADO recordset (over 650,000 records) and load that recordset into a variant array. Then I'm trying search the array to see if a specified string value exists in it using a Binary Search function I found online. I'm getting the error message "Subscript Out Of Range" when I call the Binary Search function. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
Dim arrItems() As Variant
'gXRst and gXCon are global variables declared elsewhere. They are not the problem here.
With gXRst
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .LockType = adLockReadOnly
    .Open "SELECT item_cd FROM xmsalinv ORDER BY item_cd ASC", gXCon
End With

arrItems = gXRst.GetRows(gXRst.RecordCount)
gXRst.Close
MsgBox BinarySearch(arrItems(), "491588S")

Function BinarySearch(arr As Variant, search As String, _
    Optional lastEl As Variant) As Long
    Dim index As Long
    Dim first As Long
    Dim last As Long
    Dim middle As Long
    Dim inverseOrder As Boolean

    ' account for optional arguments
    If IsMissing(lastEl) Then lastEl = UBound(arr)

    first = LBound(arr)
    last = lastEl

    'Error message occurring on next line. Error 9, subscript out of range.
    ' deduct direction of sorting
    inverseOrder = (arr(first) > arr(last))

    ' assume searches failed
    BinarySearch = first - 1

    Do
        middle = (first + last) \ 2
        If arr(middle) = search Then
            BinarySearch = middle
            Exit Do
        ElseIf ((arr(middle) < search) Xor inverseOrder) Then
            first = middle + 1
        Else
            last = middle - 1
        End If
    Loop Until first > last
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetRows [returns a 2D array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but the binary search routine wants a 1D array.

Why not just use the built-in [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676117%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in the recordset object? Its quicker than a hand-rolled binary search, and much easier.

```
gXRst.MoveFirst
gXRst.Find("item_cd='491588S'")
MsgBox gXRst.Fields("item_cd").Value
```

Comment: I'm already using the find method and I'm looking for ways to speed this up. I was assuming that doing a binary search would be faster.

Comment: As a side question, do most array search routines assume a single-column, 1D array? I've had some confusion when looking at the search array routines online written by other people.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of junky hand-coded sorts in the wild, many have subtle bugs and most are "toy" sorts sorting a 1-D array.  A lot are the product of "speed freak" coders who seldom create a real program but enjoy tinkering.  Watch out for "off by one" errors in many binary search routines you can find out there too (can't handle even or odd numbers for elements for example).

You've already "spent" the resources building a Recordset, so consider using that with a tweak.

### Using Optimize:

You can improve the performance of gXRst.Find by using a client-side cursor, the correct CursorType, and creating indexes on the key(s) you're using (Optimize dynamic property):

```
With gXRst
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open "SELECT item_cd FROM xmsalinv ORDER BY item_cd ASC", _
          gXCon, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
    !item_cd.Properties("Optimize") = True
End With
```

Find first:

```
gXRst.Find "item_cd = '4915885'", , adSearchForward, adBookMarkFirst
```

Find next:

```
gXRst.Find "item_cd = '4915885'", 1, adSearchForward, adBookMarkCurrent
```

Find last:

```
gXRst.Find "item_cd = '4915885'", , adSearchBackward, adBookMarkLast
```

Noting of course that a current row position must be set before calling Find.  When in doubt use MoveFirst, MoveLast, etc.  Or use the BookMark values to start from first/last (adBookMarkCurrent is the default).

### From PowerPoint presentation (ca. 1999) *Disconnecting ADO* by Rob Macdonald:

```
Data Structures Compared

Figures below are based on a 5000 row, 4 column data structure.
    * Times are normalised on Variant Array performance
    * Array sorting is 400 times slower than iteration

            Variant Array Recordset Indexed Recordset Collection
----------- ------------- --------- ----------------- -----------
Iterate     100           2,120     2,160                 120
Find 1 (1)  100             308         2.6           0.9/212 (2)
Find n (1)  100             422        17                 393
Sort (1)    100               3.2       3.0             7,076

    (1) timings include iterating through the results
    (2) the faster time is achieved if searching by collection key is possible
```